# Adding File and Directory to Array

Tags: c#

I have this method that searches all files and folders in "C:\Sharing".

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Sharing", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And foreach shows me full path of each file. Great. However, since these are in a directory called "Sharing", I want to check and add files that are like

C:\Sharing\Jerry2022\wedding.jpg **(array: 'wedding.jpg', 'Jerry2022')**

C:\Sharing\snapshot.jpg **(array: 'snapshot.jpg')**

C:\Sharing\Newsletter\cover-june.webp **(array: 'cover-june.webp', 'Newsletter')**

So as you can see, I want to add file and subdirectory name to a string array or List, doesnt matter. Excluding "Sharing".

How can I split the results? I know I can use Substring and LastIndexOf("\") + 1 and separate the ending '' but I'm not sure how to match up the filename with the subdir name too.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What if the full path has an extra directory? `C:\Sharing\Jerry2022\photographer\wedding.jpg`

Comment: Then we account for that as being a step ahead of the root directory (Sharing)

Comment: So you want `(array: 'wedding.jpg', 'photographer')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryInfo` to get the information you want:

C#:

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Sharing");
if (directoryInfo.Exists)
{
    foreach (var fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var fileName = fileInfo.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        var directoryName = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
        // you can use split to get the directory name array
        Console.WriteLine(directoryName);
    }
}
```

I found an other way, use `Uri` for this scenario:

C#:

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Sharing", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var s in fileArray)
{
    var uri = new Uri(s);
    var uriSegments = uri.Segments.ToArray();
}
```

You will see each part of the full path, but you may need to use `.Trim('/')` for each part. Then you can use `string.Equals` to get directories which you want.

Comment: This is absolutely the answer, as I can match directories names and separate them aside to work the data. Solution was this!

Answer (score 1):

You could split the results using [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char()))

But of course you can also work with [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-fileinfo-ctor(system-string)) instead